# Android app no longer falling back to default values/strings.xml

Tags: android, string, localization, fallback

My app has been in production for over a year. We write British English terms in the default fallback values/strings.xml file, and localize some terms for US English by adding a values-en-rUS/strings.xml file. This has always worked just fine.

Now all of a sudden when the phone is set to UK English it is taking the strings from the US English file. Has Google changed the fallback order?

Comment: have you set the locale programmatically and load that config when the app is launched? If yes, the most likely reason is that the app sets the config to US english because that's what it is set to. ALternatively, something I have seen is that it takes a reboot for the apps to properly react to a locale update.

Comment: No, not setting locale programmatically anywhere. Tried several reboots, both of the dev machine and emulator and phones

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like Google changed the fallback order... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html

[image]